# Where is the publishing section in the unity editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to make a game that use voice recognition but couldn't find the publishing section in order to ask for window computers for microphone permission. When I set up the project, I used the mobile 2D template and I'm currently using the newest unity version so anyone know where the publishing section has gone. I tried to follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/voice-input-in-unity but couldn't find the publishing section when it said "The Microphone capability must be declared for an app to use Voice input.

In the Unity Editor, go to the player settings by navigating to "Edit > Project Settings > Player"
Select on the "Windows Store" tab
In the "Publishing Settings > Capabilities" section, check the Microphone capability"

So any idea on where has the publishing section gone?

Answer (score 1):

This section appears when your current build platform is Universal Windows Platform (you can switch platforms in File > Build Settings). Check this from Unity's documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsWSA.html